# GWT code splitting (with activities and places)

Tags: gwt

Without changing vast amounts of code where should the `GWT.runAsync()` split points take place in a large GWT project using activities and places, that does not make use of GIN?

E.g. Does the split have to occur of every activity's `start()` member producing lots of boilerplate code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have an open [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5129&q=activities&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) about accommodating RunAsync in ActivityManager in GWT issues, you can see sent [patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/attachmentText?id=5129&aid=2580058578631852802&name=AsyncActivityManager.patch&token=14blZ3HTL0AoBEPyCgznw5vIi0Y:1355993687055) in this issue or wait to applying this patch in next GWT version.
It is better to call GWT.runAsync in getActivity method of your ActivityMapper class.

I have changed [GWT activities and places sample](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) so that it works with GWT code splitting and push it in [github](https://github.com/zarinfam/hello-mvp-async).

Comment: Does the fact that the patch was submitted in 2010 imply that there's no official recommendation or solution still?

Comment: Yes there is not, but you can extend ActivityManager and ActivityMapper.

Comment: Wow, the github example has really helped me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam Github example has really helped.  Did you ever try to group activities by split points? Any suggestion regarding that?

Comment: @Alex Did you ever try to group activities by split points? Any suggestion regarding that?

Comment: @Dipak I do not use activities, we implement our custom way because of activities and places shortcoming.